# QNX SDP 7.1.0 (QCC 8.3.0) -'ioctl_socket' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qnx

We have a module which makes use of `ioctl_socket()` function, I have included `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` in the `.cpp` but still throws the below error :

```
'ioctl_socket' was not declared in this scope
             if (ioctl_socket( sockFd, SIOCSETVLAN, &ifr) == -1)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the compilation error? thanks in advance.